# Define preset colors using FastLed library

Tags: led

I'm using an addressable 150 led strip and an Arduino Nano to control it, using `FastLed` library.

I'm tring do create a function `turn_on_leds`, which gets 4 parameters:

1) delay time for lighting a led in the loop, 2) direction ( not relevant for now), 3) color index for `colors` array , 4) brightness percentage.

**Problem #1**: a color array is defined to select from a preset definitions of colors ([Fastled reference](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/wiki/Pixel-reference), but when selecting `col_indx` =2, meaning `colors[2]`, leds are not lit in `Red` as they should, AND when setting `leds[i]=0xFF0000`, the right result is set.

**Problem #2**: at `loop` there is a for intended for raise bightness from 0 to 100, BUT the results are 0 for first iteration and 9 for all others.

Appreciate any HELP!!

Guy

Code:

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NUM_LEDS 10
#define BRIGHTNESS  55
#define DATA_PIN 7

char *colors[] = {0x000000,0xFFFFFF,0xFF0000,0x008000,0x0000FF}; // black, white,r,g,b
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
int t = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  //  FastLED.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);
}


void turn_leds_on(int del_1, bool dir_1, int col_indx, int bright_1) {
  if (dir_1 == true ) { // start to end
    for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_LEDS; i++) {
      leds[i] = 0xFF0000;//colors[col_indx];
      FastLED.setBrightness(bright_1*255/100);
      FastLED.show();
      delay(del_1);
    }
  }
}


void loop() {
  Serial.println(t);
  turn_leds_on(50, true, 2, 100);
  delay(1000);
  //  turn_leds_on(50, true, 0, t);
  //  delay(1000);

  if (t < 100 ) {
    t += 10;
  }
  else {
    t = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `colors` array should be `CRGB` type, not `char *`.

```
CRGB colors[] = {0x000000,0xFFFFFF,0xFF0000,0x008000,0x0000FF}; // black, white,r,g,b
```

For your second problem - you are overflowing the bounds of your LEDs array:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_LEDS; i++) {
  leds[i] = 0xFF0000;//colors[col_indx];
```

You are going from 0 to 10 inclusive. That's 11 iterations. There is no such array slice as `leds[10]`, so the value you write to it ends up overwriting the next two bytes in memory - and those happen to be occupied by the variable `t`.

Comment: thank you. that solved problem 1, what about 2 ?

Comment: @Guy.D You are overflowing the bounds of an array.

Comment: OMG , you are so RIGHT.  ThankYou!